# Can I trasport a small set of tools with me in the airplane?

Tags: air-travel, legal, airlines, hand-luggage

I was given a small set of screw drivers. A set of 8 bits and a plastic cable.

Can I transport that in hand-luggage?

I will be flying inside European Union.

[image]

Comment: From where to where?

Comment: @JoErNanO updated

Comment: Do you have just the bits, or do you actually have the screwdriver handle (into which the bits go) as well?

Comment: I have the actual screw driver. But its just a plastic handle where you also keep the bits. This was a one of those company gifts. Not a real "hard core" tool.

Comment: I've never had any comment about these, not even from the US TSA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### EU Regulations

[The list of prohibited items drawn up by the EU doesn't mention screwdriver bits explicitly.](http://ec.europa.eu/transport/modes/air/security/doc/info_travellers_restricted_art.pdf) I would not take this to mean that screwdriver bits are indeed allowed in your hand-luggage. Rather, these regulations are often left vague enough so as to allow the airport security staff enough wiggle room to rule on a case-by-case fashion. However, the linked document has an entire paragraph on workmen's tools which includes all of the following in the list of items forbidden in hand-luggage:

> d. **workmen's tools** (tools capable of being used either to cause serious injury or to threaten the safety of aircraft), including:
>
> - crowbars,
> - drills and drill bits, including cordless portable power drills,
> - tools with a blade or a shaft of more than 6 cm capable of use as a weapon, such as
>     screwdrivers and chisels,
> - saws, including cordless portable power saws,
> - blowtorches,
> - bolt guns and nail guns;

An over-zealous airport security staff member might consider as either screwdrivers, drill bits or both, and thus might disallow you from carrying them on the plane in your hand-luggage. As usual, to be safe, I'd put these in my check-in luggage.

### TSA and CATSA Regulations

For completeness sake, note that [TSA allows screwdrivers of length ≤ 7in to be carried in hand-luggage](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/prohibited-items):

[image: TSA prohibited items list]

Similarly, [the Canadian Air Transport Security Authority (CATSA) seems to allow tools of length ≤ 6cm in hand-luggage](http://www.catsa.gc.ca/complete-item-list?keys=tools&submit.x=0&submit.y=0&field_wtp_category_tid=All&nid=):

[image: CATSA allows tools of length ≤ 6cm in hand-luggage]

Once again, if the value of your screwdriver bits is too high to risk having them confiscated at the airport, I would check them in regardless of what the regulations say. Better be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

> I was given a small set of screw drivers. A set of 8 bits and a plastic cable.
>   Can I transport that in hand-luggage?
>   I will be flying inside European Union.

Not with any certainty of their not being confiscated, regardless of what rules may or may not say.

I have had more innocuous items than that confiscated (not in Europe).

FWIW, if it was in a pack pocket surrounded by coins and other small miscellaneous metal paraphenalia then a medium size Swiss Army Knife might make the trip from London to Paris undetected.(Or may not).
(As may happen if a passenger discovered that they were carrying it only after their main baggage had been checked*.)(Don't ask me how I know). That being the case, the same may apply to a very small toolkit. If this did happen the passenger would probably want their awareness of the tools inclusion to be plausibly deniable.

- Said hypothetical knife may have (hypothetically) been the one which fell foul of a Chinese inland airline security check about 10 years later. Doh!